# No static exports found in typescript library bundle

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have a class Style in a file Style.ts:

```
export class Style
{
    ...
}
```

This class has some properties, some methods and a constructor as well as several import statements for other class dependencies. The class is currently being used by other classes through a standard es6 import statement:

```
import { Style } from "../Theming/Style";
```

If I give this file as an entry point for webpack (one of several) it produces this at the end of the bundle:

```
/***/ 0:  
/*!***************************************************************!*\
/* ./src/Forms/Theming/Style ***!
\********************************************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

module.exports = __webpack_require__(/*! ./src/Forms/Theming/Style 
*/"./src/Forms/Theming/Style.ts");
```

And the Style class does not appear in the bundle. If I don't give this file as an entry point it gets ignored completely, even if its being used by another module that is included as an entry point. Also, I'm giving this one class as an example as this is happening with several files and I currently don't understand why.

This is my webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
    watch: false,
    mode: "development",
    devtool: false,
    entry:
    {
        main: common.entryPoints
    },
    output:
    {
        path: __dirname + "/../dist",
        filename: "forms-library.js",
        library: "FormsLibrary",
        libraryTarget: "umd"
    },
    module:
    {
        rules:
        [
            { test: /\.ts$/, use: "ts-loader", exclude: "/node_modules/" }
        ]
    },
    resolve:
    {
        extensions: [ ".ts" ],
        modules: [ "./src" ]
    }
}
```

This is my typescript config:

```
{
    "exclude": ["node_modules","dist", "build"],
    "compilerOptions": 
     {
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],             
        "sourceMap": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es6"
     }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is currently happening? Thank you!

Comment: I tried this and when I list `Style.ts` as an entry point, the class is correctly included in the output.  Can you publish a repository that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi Matt, sure thing, you can find the entire project here: https://github.com/walter-sharp/kuumba-forms (there may be differences in the config files as I've been trying to fix the issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Style` class is referenced only by type annotations, so after the TypeScript compiler strips those type annotations, Webpack is correctly determining that the class will never be used starting from your entry point at runtime.  If you add an actual call to `new Style(...)` somewhere, the `Style` class should be included.  Or if it is only meant to be instantiated by clients of your library, you'll need to re-export it from the entry point so that clients can access it.

Comment: Yeah re-exporting it fixed the issue, thanks Matt! I don't really understand why this is happening though since I was importing the class using an import statement, why does that not force it to import the module? Or is this Typescript trying to optimize things?

Comment: TypeScript removes imports that aren't used at runtime.  I presume that's for optimization and/or to avoid warnings about unused imports from subsequent tools.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this has already been resoled, but I found myself having the same issue and after a lot of digging around, I fixed it by including `libraryTarget` in my `output` property of the Webpack Configuration:

```
// ...
output: {
  path: root('./dist'),
  filename: 'index.js',
  libraryTarget: 'umd' // <-- this line
},
// ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but I have a react component library transpiled from Typescript into Javascript and this solved the import problem I was having. Thank you!